# Can I convert a Google Doc to a MS Word document?

Tags: google-drive, microsoft-word

How can I convert a Google Doc to MS Word document?

Answer (score 10):

You can download and convert a Google Docs to a MS Office Word Document.

Click the arrow on the Actions link for the file you want to convert and select `Download...` (Note the ellipsis)

[image: Google Docs - Actions]

The following `Convert and Download` window will appear, select the Microsoft Word option

[image: Google Docs - convert and download]